# SegmentCacheManager - warmup segments strategy/SQL in parallel?

Tags: mondrian

We run Mondrian (version "3.7.preview.506") on a Tomcat Webserver. 
We have some long running MDX-queries.
For example: The first calculation takes 276.764 ms and sends 84 SQL requests to the database (30 to 700ms for each SQL statement).

We see that the SQL-Statements are not executed in parallel - only two "mondrian.rolap.agg.SegmentCacheManager$sqlExecutor" are running at the same time.

1. Is there a way to force Mondrian/olap4j to execute the SQL statments more in parallel?
2. What is about the property "mondrian.rolap.maxSqlThreads" which is set to 100 by default?

Afterwards we execute the same MDX query and the calculation is finished in 4.904 ms.
Conclusion - if the "internal cache" (mondrian.rolap.agg.SegmentCacheManager) has loaded the segments the calculation is executed without any database request - but ...
3.How can we "warm up" the internal cache?

One way we tried was to rewrite the MDX-queries - we load several month into the cache by once (*MDX-B*):

**MDX-A**: `SELECT ... ON ROWS FROM cube01 WHERE {[Time].[Default].[2017].[4]}`
becomes 
**MDX-B**: `SELECT ... ON COLUMNS, CrossJoin( ... ,{[Time].[Default].[2017].[2]:[Time].[Default].[2017].[4]})" + " ON ROWS FROM cube01`

The rewriten MDX query takes 1.235.128 ms (244 SQL requests) - afterwards we execute our orgin MDX query (*MDX-A*) and the calculating takes 6.987 ms
- the interessting part for us was, that the calculation takes longer as 5 sec. (compared with the second execution of the same query),
even if we did not have any SQL request anymore.
The warm-up of the cache does not work as expected (in our opinion) - *MDX-B* takes much longer to collect data with one statement, as we would run the the monthly execution in three steps (Febrary to April) - and the calculation in memory also takes more time - why - how does loading segmentation really works?

4. What is the best practice to load the segments to speed up calculation in memory?
5. Is there a way to feed the "Mondrian-Cube" with simple SQL statements?

Thanks in advance.

---

Fact table with 3.026.236 rows - growing daily

6 dimension tables.

Date dimension table 21.183 rows.

We have monitored our test classes with JVM's VisualAdmin.

Mondrian 3.7.preview.506 - olap4j-1.1.0

Database: Oracle Database 11g Release 11.2.0.4.0 - 64bit

(we tried to use also memSQL database, we was only 50% faster ...)